# Treating the input for the read command as a command itself

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, read

Let's say I defined this function in the script:

```
fct1() {
  local msg1=${@}
if [[ "${verb}" = 'tru' ]]; then
  echo "I say $msg1"
  sleep 1
  echo "i repeat"
  sleep 1
  echo "I saaaaaaaaay $msg1"
else
  echo "$msg1"
fi
}
```

How would I go about making a user call this function from `read` ?

I'm thinking something like

`read fct1 "aha aha ahaaaaa"`

And the output would be:

`"I say aha aha ahaaaaa"
"I repeat"
"I saaaaaaaaay aha aha ahaaaaa"`

Basically, how do I use the input on `read` and not store it in a variable, but use it as a command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted the message do be read as one line from stdin (entered by the user when the script is used in a terminal) and then passed as argument to the function, you could do:

```
fct1 "$(line)"
```

`line` is no longer a standard command but still fairly widespread. You could replace it with `head -n1`, but with some implementations, it could read more than one line (though it outputs only one) when the input is not coming from a terminal device.

With `bash`'s `read` you would have to store it in a variable. That's what `read` is for, store input in a variable.

```
IFS= read -r line && fct1 "$line"
```

With `zsh`'s `read`, you can use the `-e` option which *echoes* the read data instead of storing it in a variable, so `line` above can be written there as `IFS= read -re`:

```
fct1 "$(IFS= read -re)"
```

(that's less efficient than using `read` with a variable as we need to fork a process so zsh can read `read`'s output).

Of course, you could also replace your:

```
local msg1=${@}
```

with

```
local msg1; IFS= read -r msg1 || return
```

Comment: So if I would do something like define function `readfct() {;${x};}` and then `read x;readfct`, it would execute whatever is in `x` as an actual command?

Comment: @iamAguest, yes. `${x}` or `${x}` applies split+glob on the expansion of `$x`, the first word resulting of that is taken as a command name (builtin, function or external; not keyword nor alias) and the list of words passed to that command. You'd use `"$x"` for the content to be one command with no argument, and `eval "$x"` for the content of `$x` to be taken as shell code to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

The `read` utility does not allow using callbacks (I'm not sure any common Unix tools does).It furthermore does not output the data that's is read.

What you would have to do is to wrap the `read` call in a function that takes what the user is providing and outputs it back as you describe. Alternatively, use some other tool to read the input and produce the wanted output, like `awk`.

Also, in general, using `variable=$@` is not well defined.  If you want the command line arguments as a list of space-delimited values, use `variable="$*"` instead (assuming the default value of the `IFS` variable).

Comment: `"$*"` is only space separated if `$IFS` starts with space (as it is by default) or is unset.

Comment: `awk` and most text utilities would read more than one line of input though when the input is not a terminal nor a regular file (for regular files, they still read more, but some seek back to appear as if they'd read only one line). You could use the `line` utility (no longer standard though) which reads one character  at a time to avoid reading more than one line.

Comment: While `bash`'s `read` doesn't echo back what it reads (except with `-e` on stderr when stdin is a terminal), but `zsh`'s one does with `-e` or `-E` (for _echo_, not _edit_ like with `bash`). So `zsh`'s `IFS=  read -re` works like `line`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite unusual request ... hmmm ... in order to get some input from the terminal into the positional parameter list of that function, try

```
fct1 "$(cat)"
dfergerg
I say dfergerg
i repeat
I saaaaaaaaay dfergerg
```

That will keep `cat`ting until you enter a EOF (CTRL-D) character. Make sure the `vert` variable is set to `tru` outside the function.